# Marshalling a complex type xml element using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I am running into multiple namespaces while marshalling a complex type Element(contains list of Element in it Example: device see below) using JAXB. Appreciate any help in getting the desired output as mentioned below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held"        
xmlns:ns2="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id" 
xmlns:ns3="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:vendor" responseTime="10">    
<ns2:device xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id"
            xmlns:ns2="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held">
    <uri>http://stackoverflow.com</uri>
</ns2:device>
```

Here device is a complex type element as defined in the extension schema. I am working with many schema's.

But the desired output without the extra namespaces around device complex type element is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held" responseTime="10"> 
<device xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id">
    <uri>http://stackoverflow.com</uri>
 </device>
 </Request>
```

Device Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:id="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="device" type="id:deviceIdentity" />
<xs:complexType name="deviceIdentity">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any xmlns:id="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:geopriv:held:id"
                processContents="strict" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Marshalling Code:

```
        final JAXBElement<String> uri = objectFactory.createUri(uri);

        Element elt = XmlMarshaller.getDomElement(uri, String.class);
        final Device device = objectFactory.createDevice();
        if (elt != null) {
            device.getAnies().add(elt);
        }

        elt = XmlMarshaller.getDomElement(device, Device.class);
        Request.getAnies().add(elt);


Element getDomElement(final Object object, final Class<?> clazz) throws JAXBException {

    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    final DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, res);
    final Element elt = ((Document) res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();

    return (elt);
}
```